# Openedge 11 Microsoft SQL Server Dataserver performance

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We are in a migration process from a Progress DB to use the Dataserver to a SQL Server database, and we have had a lot of issues, specifically  with performance where the dataserver is not able to produce server side joins for a lot of queries.

In the datasheet for Openedge 11 it says this has been improved, but anyone has an idea of how much improvement they've made.

As an example, every query involving two buffers where the second one is FIRST/LAST wouldn't be joined at server side, has this been changed?

Many thanks,

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check page 175 of the OpenEdge Data Management for MS SQL Server PDF for an answer to this question - there are a whole pile of conditions that apply, as well as a number of control settings that'll affect performance.